# Building a pixelart drawing component for React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, drawing

Im currently developing a pixelart drawing app in React Native but ive been unsucceful as i cannot find any helpful resources on how to even draw something to the drawing surface,
I have tried looking and looking yet i cant find a way of raster drawing to a surface/image/view, i could only find paths and svg stuff not to mention zooming in and out and how that will affect the drawing and the drawing coordinates.

Essentially how do i create a canvas in which the user can draw on and can have its position and scale change yet still place a pixel relative to the drawing.

Its been extremely confusing and i dont know what to do!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please take a look at [ask] and revise your question to be about one specific technical issue.

Comment: Done is there anything in specific i might need to add? @Abe